# Core data functionality without using coredata

Tags: objective-c, ios, sqlite, core-data

I am maintaining an iOS app that currently uses Core Data to get data off a db and populate a table view. A new requirement has come up that the entire database must be encrypted with SQLCypher and based on my research, Core Data refuses to play nice with the cypher. So it has been decided that coredata support be removed and database calls now must be made by hand. In this case, is there any library/project out there that emulates the functionality of the NSFetchedResults in CoreData that manages the db interaction and plays nice with TableViews?

I am looking for advice on architecting the project in a way to have the lowest amount of code littered with sql statements to do the db interaction. Can anyone please advice on how this can be accomplished?

Thanks

Comment: Do they want to encrypt the whole database as a file or just the entries in the database? Because I once had to encrypt part of the entries in a Core Data database and it was easy to accomplish...

Comment: I believe the entire db. Its a strict requirement apparently from the higher ups

Comment: mmh ok I posted my solution anyways, maybe "the higher ups" will change their decision when they see the amount of work it will need for integrating SQLCypher...

Comment: @benjamin83 - Encrypting individual entries is incredibly insecure, and doesn't meet many strict security standards.

Comment: We have some medical apps, and in order to meet HIPAA standards we find we must use SQLCiper (or something similar) and "roll our own" layer on top.  (Since we've been doing this since before Core Data, we haven't modeled any of our support layer off of Core Data.)

Comment: Apple used to have a sample project called "SQLite Books" that provided an example of building an object graph and lazily loading object properties from a SQL database. But it's no longer available for download officially. If you can find a copy it may be beneficial to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this solution can help you keep Core Data and provide encryption for the contents.

Let's say we have a Core Data object named MyObject with one attribute MyData. Then set the property **transient** for this attribute in the CoreData model. Now define a second attribute MySecretData with the attribute type **Binary Data**. This is where the actual data will be stored.

Now create a category on the NSManagedObject subclass like this:

```
@interface MyObject (Access)

- (NSData*)myData;
- (void)setMyData:(NSData*)value;

@end

@implementation MyObject (Access)

- (NSData*)MyData {
    NSMutableData * tmpValue;

    [self willAccessValueForKey:@"MyData"];
    tmpValue = [self primitiveValueForKey:@"MyData"];
    [self didAccessValueForKey:@"MyData"];

    if(!tmpValue) {
        NSData *encryptedData = [self valueForKey:@"MySecretData"];
        if(encryptedData) {            
            tmpValue = [NSMutableData dataWithData:encryptedData];
            BOOL success = [tmpValue decryptWithKey:nil];
            if (!success) {
                // Error Handling here
            }
            tmpValue = [tmpValue zlibInflate];
            [self setPrimitiveValue:tmpValue forKey:@"MyData"];
        }
        else {
            tmpValue = nil;
            [self setMyData:tmpValue];
        }
    }
    return tmpValue;
}

- (void)setMyData:(NSData *)data {
    NSData* tmpValue;
        [self willAccessValueForKey:@"MyData"];
        tmpValue = [self primitiveValueForKey:@"MyData"];
        [self didAccessValueForKey:@"MyData"];

        if([tmpValue isEqual:data])
        return;

        [self willChangeValueForKey:@"MyData"];
        [self setPrimitiveValue:data forKey:@"MyData"];
        [self didChangeValueForKey:@"MyData"];
        NSMutableData* encryptedData = nil;
        if (data != nil) {
            encryptedData = [NSMutableData dataWithData:data];
            encryptedData = [encryptedData zlibDeflate];
            BOOL success = [encryptedData encryptWithKey:nil];
            if (!success) {
                // Error Handling here
            }

        }
        [self setPrimitiveValue:encryptedData forKey:@"MySecretData"];
}

@end
```

In this case the data is encrypted and also deflated. From your code you can access MyData as usual. Inside the Core Database all values will be encrypted. Of course you have to use proper crypto functions.

Comment: Keep in mind that, when using this scheme, none of your key fields can be encrypted.  And it's not particularly secure.

Comment: @Hot Licks: In my case there were some fields that had to be secured if someone copies the database file and opens it with another application. Could you explain why this is not particularly secure? I'm really interested because it's in use in an app.

Comment: Short sequences that are repeatedly re-encrypted using the same key are quite susceptible to a "known plaintext" attack.  Basically, a bored college hacker could break the code, in many cases.  Something like SQLCipher encrypts entire "pages" of data at once, and does so using a "salt" value, so that a known plaintext attack is essentially impossible.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a good, easy answer. Some possibilities:

- iOS can encrypt its filesystem automagically. This would be transparent to Core Data, you just have to make sure that it's "unlocked" before you access any files. Obviously this wouldn't use SQLCypher (whatever that is)
- I'm not sure how SQLCypher works, but you might be able to write your own NSPersistentStore that talks to an encyrpted database. This, again, would be transparent to Core Data, though it may not be possible. It all depends on how SQLCypher works
- Write your own Core Data-like layer. As far as I know there's nothing quite like it... I mean, why would you write your own when Apple's is always available (if you have anything above iOS3 at least)

It's a lot of work, which ever way you look at it.

Comment: the app currently isnt using any useuful core data features (caching/prefetching) at the moment so its really only the core functionality that would need to be emulated.

Comment: SQLCipher keeps the entire DB encrypted (each sector individually), rather than having to decrypt into a temp copy when actively using the DB, or encrypt/decrypt individual fields.  Both of these latter schemes have serious security exposures.

Comment: @HotLicks Not sure how Apple's solution works, but neither of the other two options requires you to decrypt to a temp copy.